# How to show Force Stop dialog for a particular application

Tags: android

I have a list of few applications.
When I select any application, I want to show a force stop dialog as Settings application shows.

How can I do this ?
I am able to show dialog for uninstalling any application as shown below.
Can we show force stop dialog in the same way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we show force stop dialog in the same way?

"Force stop" is not a dialog. "Force Stop" is a button on the app's screen in the Settings app. You can bring up that Settings screen on some devices using an [`ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS) `Intent` with `startActivity()`.

Comment: Yes "Force stop" is a button.
In my case I do not want to show Settings screen.

To uninstall any app, I used below code -
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package: "package name");
startActivity(intent);

And it shows the above dialog.

So I was just wondering if I Can show a similar dialog to "Force stop" an app.

Comment: @Clara: No, you cannot force-stop an app.